# Como saber quantos dias tem o mês atual?

Tags: mysql, sql, data

Como saber quantos dias tem o mês atual MySQL, exemplo: `setembro = 30dias`

Motivo:

Tenho uma meta : `exemplo: 1.000,000`

Preciso pegar o valor da meta e dividir pela quantidade de dias tem no mês atual para retornar o valor da meta diária.

Comment: E a informação base para achar o último dia vem de onde?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(data)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Lastday.sql).

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day).

Answer (score 5):

Neste contexto utilizaria duas functions, a `CURDATE()` para saber a data do dia e a `LAST_DAT()` que retorna o último dia do mês a partir de uma data.

```
SELECT LAST_DAY( CURDATE() ) as DIAS_MES
```

CURDATE() - [Documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

LAST_DAY() - [Documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day)

Answer (score 2):

Apenas complementando a informação, como o amigo quer o número de dias.

```
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY( data_field )) as DIAS_MES;
```